# 10.11.2: QuickLook and thumbnails crashing finder

Tags: finder, macos, crash, preview, quicklook

I have a strange problem: Finder crashes ("not responding") after performing one of these:

- pressing `space` on a file that can be previewed with QuickLook, e.g. a sound file or an image
- simply selecting a file that can be previewed with QuickLook when the finder displays the instant QuickLook pane

Also, all my thumbnails are not displayed. All files are shown with their file type icon and not with a preview icon.

Any ideas? I have already removed Flip4Mac in `~/Library/Containers/QuickTime` to make sure no third party module is responsible for this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it:

`sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs /`

did repair the access rights of the folder `/private/tmp`. I suspect that Adobe Creative Cloud has altered the rights.

There have been some log lines in the console about quicklookd being not able to scan /, so that is another symptom of that problem.